# How to call Fuel UX

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, fuel

I have created a custom activity, but the UI for is off and would want it to blend into Journey Builder, hence use FuelUX. I am having issues calling it.

**Code**

I have used the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.13.0/css/fuelux.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.13.0/js/fuelux.min.js"></script>
    <title>Send Letter</title>
</head>
<body class="fuelux">
<div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
        <input class="sr-only" type="checkbox" value="option1" data-toggle="#hereKittyKitty">
        <span class="checkbox-label">I love kittens.</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="hereKittyKitty" class="alert bg-info">Great. Meow, too!</div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
  <label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only" type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">Custom checkbox unchecked on page load</span>
  </label>
    </div>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2">
  <label class="checkbox-custom checked" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only" checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">Custom checkbox checked on page load</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox3">
  <label class="checkbox-custom disabled" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">Disabled custom checkbox unchecked on page load</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox4">
  <label class="checkbox-custom checked disabled" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">Disabled custom checkbox checked on page load</span>
  </label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result**

The code renders this:

[image]

Clearly I am calling it wrongly, and would appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the exact theme that Marketing Cloud uses then you'll also need to reference the mctheme css. Try it out with the following

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.16.0/css/fuelux.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux-mctheme/1.15.4/css/fuelux-mctheme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also give form builder a go to ensure you get the right syntax

http://getfuelux.com/formbuilder.html